# web browser not opening

Tags: windows-vista, virus, internet-connection

I had a virus adware on my desktop. I cleaned it using AVG.

Now no browser will open, though the Internet connection is fine.

When trying to open any browser I get a dialog box that says it can't find that location. This happens to all my browsers. I even downloaded firefox on my laptop and installed it on the desktop and still get the same response -  `Windows can't find the location`. This all started when opening an email.

I'm running Windows Vista

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that a proxy server is configured (probably to 127.0.0.1/localhost) because some SpyWare will actually act as a proxy server so that it can replace/insert advertisements in HTML documents on-the-fly as they are downloaded in real-time.

SpyWare and virus removal tools don't usually change the proxy server settings because there are often legitimate reasons for them being there (e.g., in a corporate environment where proxies are required for internet access, intentional anonymization, etc.).

To change your proxy server settings:

- Control Panel
- Internet Options icon
- Connections tab
- LAN Settings button
- Proxy settings section (this is where proxy servers are usually specified)

If that's not it, then you probably need to get the WinSock Reset tool from Microsoft.  There's a document somewhere on Microsoft's support web site, but this document is a bit of a moving target so you'll need to search for the keywords "winsock" and "reset" at this web site:  http://support.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't guarantee these will solve your problems, and there are no guarantees... but here is the suite we use at work when one of our clients gets infected...

[malwarebytes](http://malwarebytes.org/)
[superantispyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/)
[hitmanpro](http://www.surfright.nl/en/hitmanpro)
[ESET online](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner)

and, IF you're feeling **very** adventurous, you can try

[combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix)

But i would not recommend combofix unless you're quite skilled, or under the supervision of your local geek.